# Can we customize omni channel logic to distribute cases based on Case Creation Date

Tags: omnichannel

Omni Channel queues distributes cases, based on Date/Time the case is assigned to the queue.  Can we customize this logic to look for some other attribute such as Case Creation Date. 
Scenario :  A new case is created and assigned to the Queue “A”. There were already 25 cases in the queue. The newly cases when assigned to the queue is 26th in the queue. After the first 25 cases are distributed, the 26th case is pushed to the agent. Agent realize the case was misrouted. And should have be assigned to Queue “B”. Agent updates the case owner to Queue”B” and then close the case tab  Queue B already had 50 cases in it. This transferred case goes and sit in 51st position. This case had already spent some waiting time in Queue “A” now due to the transfer it again has to wait until first 50 cases are cleared from the queue. We want the cases to be distributed based on Case Creation Date. How, can we ensure, that position the transferred gets in Queue B is based on its creation date relative to other cases in Queue “B”. It could be the first in Queue “B” or somewhere in middle (based on backlog in Queue “B”)

Answer (score 1):

create a queue for transferred cases and add that queue to the omni-routing for the other team.  put that queue's priority above the normal queue and cases assigned there will get send to the B team members first.